# Book set in a dream-world type setting with a female protagonist

Tags: story-identification, books, dreams

I'm looking for a book series I read as a teen. Within the past 10-12 years. I want to say it was a trilogy but I could have just read all books available at the time.

It had to do with a dreamscape type world, almost like lucid dreaming. Main character was female. I think the cover has smoke drawn on it and each book cover was a different color smoke.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There's not much here about the content of the book, just a female protagonist and a dreamscape setting.  Do you remember any events or plot points at all?  Did she have any allies?  Who was her opponent?

Answer (score 1):

This could be the [Inkheart series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkheart_series) by [Cornelia Funke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornelia_Funke), originally published in German, translated into English by [Anthea Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthea_Bell).

- The first three books of the series, *Inkheart*, *Inkspell*, and *Inkdeath* were published in 2003, 2005, and 2007, respectively, compatible with your time frame and, back then, being a trilogy.
- The trilogy deals the with people having the ability to pull characters from a story in a book by reading it (so these characters suddenly find themselves in the real world), or read themselves into a story. They could also alter the story by making up a new part and reading it. This matches your "lucid dreaming" description.
- The main character, Meggie Folchart, is female.
- The English language paperback(!) edition by Chicken House has flame/smoke/dust-like multicolored covers (Amazon claims it was published on Jan 1st, 2011, which would put it outside your time frame by 2 weeks). You can find the cover images by doing an image search on the book titles.

Answer (score 0):

The devouring by Simon holt! Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to SF&F! Could you please add a few details as to why you believe this is the answer? Mention a few ways the plot/characters line up with OP's description.